# MPMusicPlayerController and playing a bundled song

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

how can i play a song file bundled with the application using MPMusicPlayerController ?

code that i tried,

```
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"song1" ofType:@"mp3"];
MPMusicPlayerController *myMusicPlayer=[[MPMusicPlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
[myMusicPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MPMusicPlayer` controller is only for playing items from the user's iPod library.  The `AVAudioPlayer` will play encoded files from your app's sandbox, and you should be able to convert this code to use `AVAudioPlayer` easily enough... looks like it would be:

```
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"song1" ofType:@"mp3"]; 
AVAudioPlayer *myMusicPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
        initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]
        error:nil];
[myMusicPlayer play];
```

Comment: by the way, it should be `error:NULL`, because that argument is a pointer to a pointer, so it is a pointer to a plain old data type, not a pointer to an object

Answer (score 0):

Better use AVAudioPlayer for playing mp3 from bundle.
Even apple insist this, it is easy to set audio session for AVAudioPlayer.(if you are looking to play audio when iPhone is sleeping)
MPMusicPlayerController is usually use to play iPod music.
but you can select any as per your requirement.